# If $A$ is dense in $X$ then $X\setminus A$ is nowhere dense

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A$ is dense in $X$. Let $B^o$and $\bar{B}$ denote the interior ad closure of a set $B$. Then
$$\left(\overline{X\setminus A}\right)^o=(X\setminus A^o)^o=X\setminus \bar{A}=\emptyset$$
Hence $X\setminus A$ is nowhere dense.

Is my proof correct? And is the converse true?

Comment: No.  The rationals are dense;  so are the irrationals.

Comment: where did i go wrong in the proof?

Comment: What does $A^o$ denote?

Comment: Since $X=\mathbb R,A=\mathbb Q$ is a counterexample, why don't you try substituting $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=\mathbb Q$ into $$\left(\overline{X\setminus A}\right)^o=(X\setminus A^o)^o=X\setminus \bar{A}=\emptyset,$$  and figure out which "$=$" is wrong?

Comment: Yes, the converse is dense: the complement of a nowhere dense set is dense. I can't advise you on how to prove that fact, since you haven't revealed what definition of "nowhere dense set" you are using.

Comment: @bof $A$ is nowhere dense if the interior of its closure is empty. This is the definition i am using. And I have understood why the converse is true. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Extending William Elliot's comment: Your second equation is wrong, as you can see in his example:

$$\left({\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}^o}\right)^o=\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus \emptyset\right)^o=\mathbb{R},$$
but $${\mathbb{R}\setminus\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}=\emptyset.$$